# How do I write the opposite of this migration?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, polymorphic-associations

My migration right now :

```
class CreateActivities < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :activities do |t|
      t.integer :account_id, :null => false
      t.integer :target_id, :null => false
      t.string  :target_type, :null => false
      t.string  :event_type, :null => false
      t.integer :employee_id
      t.string  :name
      t.timestamps
    end

    add_index :activities, [:target_id, :target_type]
```

With this I can now call a target like so :

```
Activity.first.target
```

And it will bring up the target_id, based on the target_type.

How would I do the opposite of that so that I can select a target, and if it has any associated Activities, they will show up?

Like so :

```
Job.find(1234).activities
# Where Job.find(1234) is the target_id of many activities.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand right, this should do it:

```
class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :activities, :conditions => ['target_type = ?', 'Job'], :as => :target
end
```

Comment: Hmm.. this returned : `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'activities.job_id' in 'where clause': SELECT `activities`.* FROM `activities` WHERE (`activities`.job_id = 343 AND (target_type = 'Job')) ORDER BY activities.created_at DESC`

Comment: Ah, I think this did it coupled with your suggestion : `has_many :activities, :conditions => ['target_type = ?', 'Job'], :as => :target`